# Operation issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Recently, I was working with javascript.
Here's my example.

Working code:

```
const start = index - 4 >= 0 ? index - 4 : 0
const end =   index + 4 > this.props.initialMarkers.length
            ? this.props.initialMarkers.length
            : index + 4
        for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          newData.push(this.props.initialMarkers[i])
        }
```

Not working code:

```
    for (let i = index - 4 >= 0 ? index - 4 : 0; i <= index + 4 > this.props.initialMarkers.length
        ? this.props.initialMarkers.length
        : index + 4; i++) {
      newData.push(this.props.initialMarkers[i])
    }
```

Why my second code is not working? Please help me.

Comment: you need to add braces in expressions, like `(index - 4)`

Comment: Question is about working code; belongs on code review

Comment: Then how does it works in working code?

Answer (score 1):

> Why my second code is not working? Please help me.

Your problem is with this part

```
i <= index + 4 > this.props.initialMarkers.length
```

basically <= and > has same level of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) so unless you do a grouping

```
i <= ( index + 4 > this.props.initialMarkers.length ?  this.props.initialMarkers.length : index + 4 );
```

js engine will execute `i <= index + 4` first. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add braces to expressions:

```
// calculation works with braces preference so you will get desired output 
// same as it was with start and end variables

for (let i = 1; i <= (((index + 4) > this.props.initialMarkers.length)
  ? this.props.initialMarkers.length
  : (index + 4)); i++) {
  newData.push(this.props.initialMarkers[i])
}
```

And what you have tried is giving different result (as per mathematics operator used without braces) :

```js
let index = 5; // static value 

for (let i = index - 4 >= 0 ? index - 4 : 0; i <= index + 4 > 6
        ? 6
        : index + 4; i++) { // 6 is static value for this.props.initialMarkers.length
  console.log('start', i);
  console.log('end value without breaces:', i <= index + 4 > 6
        ? 6
        : index + 4); // your condition
  console.log('end', ((i <= ((index + 4) > 6))
    ? 6
    : (index + 4))); // with breces

break; // added break as some time it will go in infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add braces

```
for (let i = (index - 4 >= 0 ? index - 4 : 0); i <= (index + 4 > this.props.initialMarkers.length
    ? this.props.initialMarkers.length
    : index + 4); i++) {
  newData.push(this.props.initialMarkers[i])
}
```